# Javascript - Replacing Text using option

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I'm trying to replace the text "JSON String Here" but when I select an item from the options, it disappears. I'm new to programming Javascript, can someone take a look at this? THanks!

```
<title>Local Testing</title>

 <script>

    function swapJson(){

      var div = document.getElementById("jsonToSwap");
      var dropdown = document.getElementById("dd");
      div.src = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value; 
      document.write(div.src);

    };

 </script>
```

```
<div id="jsonToSwap">JSON String Here</div>

<select id="dd" onChange="swapJson()">
    <option value="1" id="1">Headset</option>
    <option value="2" id="2">Taxi</option>
    <option value="3" id="3">Buildings</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Do you know how the code is supposed to work? Because saying "this doesn't work" does not show the requisite minimum effort on your part.

Comment: Not saying it doesnt work. It's just that I've been working for this in hours and I dont get the results i need.

Comment: @axrwkr - Im trying to replace the text by the value on each options. (1 ,2 ,3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

change the line that reads

```
div.src = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

to this

```
div.innerText = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
```

so the whole thing will look like this

```
<script>

    function swapJson(){

      var div = document.getElementById("jsonToSwap");
      var dropdown = document.getElementById("dd");
      div.innerText = dropdown.options[dropdown.selectedIndex].value;
    };

 </script>
```

Example
http://jsfiddle.net/FxwQW/1/

Comment: thanks axrwkr - I already tried that before posting this, but I'm getting "headset", "building" and "taxi", instead of 1, 2, or 3.